# Is there any way to return all rows when parameter is empty in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my code to filter values based on parameters.  I want to move it into to a single line. Is there any option available in laravel4?

```
    if($network) //when $network variable has a value.(i will have the same thing for orderby, customer, etc..)
    {
        return  $deals=$mobiles->deals()->where('network','=',$network)->get();// ->orderby($orderby);
    }
    else
    {
        return  $deals=$mobiles->deals()->get();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im wondering why nobody suggested to **use `LIKE` instead of `=`.** I did like this, and works very well.:) I can have very dynamic filtering with many fields.  **Make sure the variable in where is set to `null` when you want to return all element.**

My code become

```
$sorttype=$orderby[0]=='-'?"desc":"asc"; //To get based on assenting or dissenting order
$orderby=$orderby[0]=='-'?substr($orderby, 1):$orderby; //just removing the first element if - existing, because that is just a flag. 

if(!$network){$network=null;} //set to null
if(!$orderby){$orderby='id';} //set to id when there no order by 


return  $deals=$mobiles->deals()
        ->where('network','LIKE',$network)
        ->orderby($orderby,$sorttype)
        ->get();
```

Comment: A `LIKE` is way more less efficient than an equals comparison, that's the thing ^^

Comment: But, For filtering purpose  **LIKE** isnt ok?

Answer (score 2):

Go with a ternary:

```
return $network ? $mobiles->deals()->where('network','=',$network)->get() : $mobiles->deals()->get();
```

Comment: What if there is my fields to filter? And if there is an orderby or group by. The code will become more complicated. laravel may have an easy way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

A more clean way than ternary suggested by @moonwave99 (in my opinion) is to add a [scope](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) to your model.

```
public function scopeNetwork($query, $network = null) {
    if (null !== $network)
        $query->where('network', $network);

    return $query;
}
```

You can then use

```
return $mobiles->deals()->network($network)->get();
```

Comment: This is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **incredibly** round-about way of doing this... Id recommend @moonwave99's solution, but you can pass a closure to `where()`.  That, mixed with a boolean, and `whereNotNull()` can do it.  Technically, it's one line of code, but I've broken it apart for the sake of readability.

**Easy way:**

```
return $network ? $mobiles->deals->where('network',$network)->get() : $mobiles->deals->get();
```

**Overly complicated way:**

```
 return $mobiles->deals->where(isset($network) ? function($query) use ($network){ 
    $query->where('network', $network);
 } : function($query){ 
    $query->whereNotNull('id');
 })->get();
```